# Mediarecorder.start() rapidly consumes lots of memory on screen record using electronjs

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, electron, screen, mediarecorder

The start method on media recorder api consumes lots of memory when trying to create blobs from a stream, it spikes up a lot in succession and takes over 4GB+ of memory for a 3 hours video and crashes sometimes, the stream recorded is also laggy, electron version is 15+, does anybody knows how to fix it? Sorry this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow so I might have made a mistake while asking a question.